# How can I customize the height and width of embedded twitter tweet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to embed a twitter tweet on my website but i couldn't change the height and width. How can I achieve this. . .

Below is the code generated by twitter for the tweet

```html
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
  <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Iustitia aims at getting justice for the sexually harrassed by using technology. Our mission is to help sexually assaulted girls back on their feet and be inculcated back into the community. The goal is to save at least 359 girls every year. <a href="https://twitter.com/savethegirl_ng/status/1281556230897569792?s=20">pic.twitter.com/tAfPl7My2A</a></p>&mdash;
  iustitia (@savethegirl_ng) <a href="https://twitter.com/savethegirl_ng/status/1281556230897569792?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">July 10, 2020</a></blockquote>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change `twitter-tweet`'s height and width like so:

CSS

```
.twitter-tweet {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

or if you'd like a more inline solution:

```html
<blockquote style="width:10px; height:10px" class="twitter-tweet">
  <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Iustitia aims at getting justice for the sexually harrassed by using technology. Our mission is to help sexually assaulted girls back on their feet and be inculcated back into the community. The goal is to save at least 359 girls every year. <a href="https://twitter.com/savethegirl_ng/status/1281556230897569792?s=20">pic.twitter.com/tAfPl7My2A</a></p>&mdash;
  iustitia (@savethegirl_ng) <a href="https://twitter.com/savethegirl_ng/status/1281556230897569792?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">July 10, 2020</a></blockquote>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```